# File in google drive and access to a non gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-account, yahoo-mail

In the google sign in form can we login using a non gmail account?
I have a case someone sharing a file in a google drive and saying that she provided access to the person's receiving the email link yahoo email.
I think providing the yahoo email/password to the Google sign-in form is not what is expected right?

Answer (score 0):

> In the google sign in form can we login using a non gmail account?

Technically yes, Google accounts can be created using any email address – they will be able to use all Google services except for Gmail.

However, the person would have had to deliberately register for an account, and the Google account would have a completely separate password from the original Yahoo email account. You won't be able to just directly login with any email account's details.

It's more likely that the file was shared by link – Google Drive has a sharing mode where everyone who has the link can access (or even edit) the shared file, without requiring a Google account at all.

Comment: `the person would have had to deliberately register for an account` what account do you mean?

Comment: I have a Google account that does not use a gmail email address. I believe this is what they mean @Jim.

Comment: @music2myear: I tried to create a new account but it only accepts gmail.com

Comment: There's a ["Use my current address" link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?hl=en#existingemail) immediately below that, isn't there?